# Paypal IPN Invalid response status: 302

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

this my ipn.php

In my log error file I have reciving this message: Invalid response status: 302

And Im reciving the  mail from inside "exception" code, someone know why ? I dont have idea why is failing... Please, I need help!!

Thank you very much

```
<?php
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__).'/ipn_errors.log');

include '../../modelo.php';
include('ipnlistener.php');
$listener = new IpnListener;
$listener->use_sandbox = true;
$listener->use_ssl = false;
$verified = $listener->processIpn($my_post_data);
 try {
//    $listener->requirePostMethod();
      $verified = $listener->processIpn();
        mail('mymail@gmail.com', 'TRY ok', 'ok');

} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
        mail('mymail@gmail.com', 'Exception', 'nok');
    exit(0);
}
mail('mymail@gmail.com', 'final del script', 'include');
?>
```

And this is my html code:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myemailpaypal@yopmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $product;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $amount;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.myweb.com/thankspage.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $bookcode; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.myweb.com/ipn.php">
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" 
        border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$listener->use_ssl = true;
```

sandbox needs ssl